# Play random mp3 file from sd card

Tags: android, media-player

I need your help.
I'm developing an android app and I need to play a random song from the sd card. I tried this way :

With this method I choose randomly a song from the folder `sdcard/Music` (this folder contains only mp3 files).

```
    public File chooseSong()
    {
        Random r=new Random();
        File path=new File("/sdcard/Music");
        File[] songsList=path.listFiles();
        int index=(r.nextInt(songsList.length));
        Toast.makeText(Main.this, "Song extract "+songsList[index],Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        return songsList[index];
    }
```

then I use this method to play the extracted song :

```
   public void play()
   {
            Toast.makeText(Main.this, "in method play() ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            try
            {
                   File f=chooseSong();
                   String path=f.getPath();
                   mpSong = new MediaPlayer();
                   mpSong.setDataSource(path);
                   mpSong.prepare();   //i think the problem is here, i receive "failed to prepare status 0x1"
                   mpSong.start();
                   Toast.makeText(Main.this, "Playing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(Main.this, "error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
    }
```

i want to know how could i play a song from the sd card of the smartphone using MediaPlayer

Comment: i want to know how could i play an mp3 file from sd card with the MediaPlayer

Comment: Thanks Imran_3,your question is solution for my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to NISHANT [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10145566/android-mediaplayer-cant-play-web-mediaprepare-failed-status-0x1):

> You Need to implement Streaming Media Player. Here is an [Example](http://davanum.wordpress.com/2007/12/29/android-videomusic-player-sample-from-local-disk-as-well-as-remote-urls/). Hope it will help you.

Just for the record, it took me like 30 seconds on [Google.de](https://www.google.de/search?q=android%20mediaplayer%200x1).

Comment: it doesn't help me, i'm a newbie in android so could you be more specific please

Comment: Hey mate. Okay, could you please log the (String) "path" into LogCat?